# App not working on other PC without SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have created an app in Visual Studio using VB.Net and SQL Server database and the app is running fine on my PC but when I use this app on another PC it runs fine but wherever is database required it gives me error. Please let me know do I need to install SQL Server on those PC where I want to use this app? Or is there any other alternate way?

Please help I'm a beginner at programming.

Comment: You have identified the error yourself. have you tested, if the database is available at the other machine?

Comment: Yes, of course - if your program uses SQL Server, then you **must** install SQL Server (or have one available on the local network) - you cannot use something and then not install it. ....

Comment: @marc_s can i use SQL server compact/SQL Lite to avoid the need to install SQL sever on other computers???

Comment: if you've written your app to use SQL Server Compact - then yes. But SQL Server Compact  is **NOT** file-level compatible with other editions of SQL Server, like SQL Server Express or Standard etc.

Comment: @marc_s and What about SQLite?

Comment: same applies: if you wrote your program for and with SQLite - sure, that works. But you cannot write an application against SQL Server, and then use SQLite on a client PC - that won't work

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your application is using the SQL Server Native Client for its connections. You can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937733.aspx

In short, you'll need to have people install the client on their machine, or use a different method to connect to the database.